# Change opacity elements of whole class

Tags: javascript, css, svg, hover

I added a SVG element in my HTML. When one element of a certain class is hovered over, I also want the other elements of the class to change opacity.

I looked for an answer all afternoon but I couldn't find the right solution.

This is my code right now. When I hover over one element of the class only one changes opacity. I want all the elements to change opacity. I think I should do it with JS but I can't figure out how.

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get('grafieken.svg', function (data) {
$(document.body) .append(data.documentElement);
init();
});
function init(){
}
</script>
<style>

.itemone:hover
{
    opacity:0.2;
}
</style>
```

Comment: do they all have the class .itemone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using JQuery hover event.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".itemon").hover(function () { // on mouse enter
        $(".itemone").css("opacity", 0.2);
    }, function () { // on mouse leave
        $(".itemone").css("opacity", 1);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Close to Konrud's solution, but I like to use classes more often. Why, you ask? Using classes to show and hide stuff might improve performance. For instance, want to animate properties? Instead of using `animate`, add a class that has a `transition` property. CSS3 use hardware acceleration whereas jQuery doesn't - as far as I know.

https://jsfiddle.net/quk9tpa8/3/

**jQuery**

```
$("div").hover(function () {
    var hoverClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("." + hoverClass).addClass("hover");
},
function () {
    $(".hover").removeClass("hover");
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to achive, but if you want to "opacity" the whole svg you can simply put a group arround it and set it there.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <g opacity="0.2">
       place your svg here   
    </g>
</svg>
```